# Deleting a row in the laravel database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete a row in the `user_guilds` table. If the `title` in the `servers` table is equal to `guild_id` in the `user_guilds` table

```
$servers[] = DB::table('servers')->select('title')->get();
$servers = json_decode(json_encode($servers), true);
DB::table('user_guilds')->where('guild_id','=', $servers)->delete();
```

I wrote like this, and it works only the first time, and about the trace of the action, it is not deleted

Comment: why ``$servers[]``  and ``$servers = json_decode(json_encode($servers), true);`` ?

Comment: @OMi Shah When I call $servers get(), it is called as a collection, and when I want to compare title with guild_id, the stdclass error is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$servers[] = DB::table('servers')->select('title')->get();
$servers = json_decode(json_encode($servers), true);
DB::table('user_guilds')->whereIn('guild_id', $servers)->delete();
```

Comment: The same thing, the first time she is deleted, and then writes this ``Invalid parameter number (SQL: delete from `user_guilds` where `guild_id` in (797157162169270273))`` where id 797157162169270273 is the id that was deleted the first time

Comment: I did it through foreach and everything worked, thank you